# Getting police certificate from France

Tags: france, documentation

I am a third country national. I was in France as an exchange student 2 years ago. Now I am in Germany. How can I get a police certificate from France?

Comment: Hello. What do you expect such a certificate would certify ?

Comment: Why do you need one? https://casier-judiciaire.justice.gouv.fr/mai-web-b3-presentation/pages/accueil.xhtml?cid=1

Answer (score 2):

The only police certificate you can have from France is the 3rd bulletin of your judicial file

This only contains (from [service-public](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F14710)):

> Le bulletin n°3 est le bulletin au contenu le plus restreint. Il comporte uniquement les condamnations les plus graves, à savoir :
>
> - Condamnations pour crimes et délits supérieures à 2 ans d'emprisonnement sans sursis, prononcées en France ou à l'étranger
> - Condamnations pour crimes et délits inférieures à 2 ans d'emprisonnement sans sursis, si le tribunal en a ordonné la mention
> - Certaines déchéances ou incapacités en cours d'exécution (par exemple, déchéance de l'autorité parentale, interdiction d'exercer une activité professionnelle)
> - Mesures de suivi socio-judiciaire et peines d'interdiction d'exercer une activité professionnelle ou bénévole impliquant un contact
>   habituel avec des mineurs

> Bulletin n°3 is the most restricted bulletin. It only shows the most serious convictions :
>
> - Convictions for misdeaminors and felonys with prison term above 2 years without repreive, in France or in a foreign country
> - Convictions for misdeaminors and felonys with prison term below 2 years without repreive, if the court ordred the mention
> - Certain interdictions or deprivations currently in force (parental authority deprival, interdiction of work...)
>   Measures of control and interdictions to occupy positions/volunteering with regular contact with minors

If anyone asks for your police certificate for France, this is the one (note that you, of course, need to be truthful about convictions, even if not appearing in that file)

You can get it [online](https://casier-judiciaire.justice.gouv.fr/mai-web-b3-presentation/pages/accueil.xhtml?cid=1)